# Ubuntu 16.04 can't find RAID

Tags: boot, upgrade, 16.04, raid, busybox

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 15.10 to 16.04, and it drops me into BusyBox with the following error:

```
Gave up waiting on root device. Common problems:
 - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
   - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   - Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
 - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/mapper/isw_dbaibaaaac_RAID5_2 does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

Here's what I know so far:

1. The boot args have not changed from what they were for 15.10
   (root=/dev/mapper/isw_dbaibaaaac_RAID5_2 libata.ignore_hpa=0 ro)
2. rootdelay=90 only causes a longer delay before the same failure.
3. /proc/modules includes dm_raid, raid456, async_memcpy, async_pq, async_xor, async_tx, and libcrc32c
4. The only item in /dev/mapper is 'control'
5. The system will still successfully load if I select a prior kernel (4.2.0-42-generic) in grub. However, I'd like to use the 16.04 kernel (4.4.0-31-generic) if possible.

Thanks in advance!